# Combining multiple linked lists into one

Tags: android, linked-list

Is it possible to put the linkLst1, linkLst2,linkLst3 into one LinkedList, like linkLst? And after that I just need to call linkLst.get(i) to add or remove object?

Thanks in advance!

```
    private LinkedList<Number> linkLst1;
    private LinkedList<Number> linkLst2;
    private LinkedList<Number> linkLst3;

   {
    linkLst1= new LinkedList<Number>();
    linkLst2= new LinkedList<Number>();
    linkLst3= new LinkedList<Number>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can you just have to make Linklist linkLast of type linkedlist as you do in java

```
LinkedList <ArrayList>list = new LinkedList<ArrayList>();
```

this is how i made linkedlist of arraylist type i think this would do what u want

Comment: Thank You. I use the idea and `LinkedList<LinkedList> linklist = new LinkedList<LinkedList>();` to create linkedlist of linkedlist.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use `addAll`.

```
private LinkedList<Number> linkList = new LinkedList<Number>();
linkList.addAll(linkLst1);
linkList.addAll(linkLst2);
linkList.addAll(linkLst3);
```

Now `linkList` contains all of the same items as the three previous combined.